# Regular expression advice

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the names in the character string:

```
str <- "Bob 1/4 F4 Mary Lou 5/1 Thomas Tank 66/19"
```

to a vector:
"Bob", "Mary Lou", "Thomas Tank"

I have the following which returns "Bob".  Can anyone tell me how to match the following globally?

```
cVec <- ""
findMatch <- regexpr("[^0-9]+", str)
cVec       <- append(cVec, regmatches(str,findMatch))
cVec
```

Ideally I'd like a list with both the name and fraction elements eg
"Bob", "1/4"
"Mary Lou", "5/1"
"Thomas Tank", "66/19"
But I suspect that F4 is going to be difficult (it's not needed).  I'd settle for the names!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the names and fractions with the following command:

```
regmatches(str, gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+( [[:alpha:]]+)?\\b|\\d+/\\d+", str))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Bob"         "1/4"         "Mary Lou"    "5/1"         "Thomas Tank"
# [6] "66/19"
```

Comment: I can't begin to describe how impressed I am. You are Jedi!  Thank-you!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know R, so I can't provide you with implementation. However, I think a solution could be made with this regex:

```
(?<=^| )[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?(?= |$)|[0-9]+/[0-9]+
```

It will match `Bob`, `1/4`, `Mary Lou`, `5/1`, `Thomas Tank`, and `66/19`, but not `F4`.

Online explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/vB8rU5

Comment: Thank you, question answered and a really nice explanation.  Appreciated and impressed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with R's regex syntax, but the following Java regex matches the whole expression (`\s` means whitespace; `\d` means a digit, `[0-9]`; `()` is a group; R seems to agree):

```
"([A-Za-z]+\\s)+(\\d+/\\d+(\\s[A-Z][\\d+])?)"
```

In Java there's a `find` method that lets you walk through pattern matches.  In R, I think it's `gregexpr`, except this gives you a list of indices, not the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day this is way to fuzzy to give a solid/general solution. But this would do the trick and you would just have to trim the names:

```
> strsplit(str, "[0-9][ 0-9F/]+[0-9]")[[1]]
[1] "Bob "          " Mary Lou "    " Thomas Tank "
```

The regular expression defines what the split looks like.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
str <- "Bob 1/4 F4 Mary Lou 5/1 Thomas Tank 66/19"
m<-gregexpr("(?i)\\b[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*\\b", str)
regmatches(str, m)
```